# How to dynamically change color pallette on ConEmu?

Tags: conemu

I am using ConEmu and  want to dynamically change color pallette if I ssh to specific machine. Is this possible? I've done some tests with App Distinct settings but was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

You may set up AppDistinct palette only for `ssh.exe`, so it is impossible to choose certain palette by server using AppDistinct.

But you may set up [Task](http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) to connect to the server and [choose palette...](http://conemu.github.io/en/NewConsole.html#syntax)

```
ssh.exe -new_console:P:"your-pal" rest-of-ssh-switches
```